# Add column with data from another stdinfo5table into viewtable in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select name into viewtable from stdinfo5
```

My error is:

> There is already an object named 'viewtable' in the database.

Can someone explain: I want column with data (adding) into `viewtable` from the `stdinfo5` table.

Thanks!

Comment: As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would bevery kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

`select ... into SomeTarget from SomeSource` will **create a physical table with the name `SomeTarget`!**

You can use `DROP TABLE SomeTarget` to delete this table (**carefull with real data!!!**) or, what might be better, use `select ... into #SomeTarget ...`.

The `#` before the name will create this table as temp table which is deleted automatically when it gets out of scope.

In your case it seems, that you do not want to delete the table, but you just want to add one more column. In this case you'd need something like `ALTER TABLE viewtable ADD TheColumnName TheColumnType;` and then use an `UPDATE` statement to fill this column. If possible, it was easier to delete the table and re-create it with the missing column...